apt install miktex requiers outdated dependencies and won't work if newer version were installed
I am trying to install MikTeX a software for writing LaTeX documents, I have
sudo apt install miktex

Suggesting on my ubuntu. But when I try to install it I get:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 miktex : Depends: libboost-locale1.65.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libhunspell-1.6-0 but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: liblog4cxx10v5 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I cannot install the dependencies via apt since they are not in apt database, I do have used
sudo apt upgrade

and also
sudo apt install -f

but none of these work! I am frustrated with MikTeX so I'm asking here for a clear way to install it on my device.

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Tried apt-get update before installing miktex?

Also, do you have the aptitude command? If not, install it and do aptitude search '~b' (to list broken packages) and aptitude search '~ahold' (to list held packages).

@Grobu sorry for late responding, I have install aptitude and tried installing miktex through that but it didn't work either. Can you give me instructions?

No worries. Can you update your initial post with the output of aptitude search '~b' and aptitude search '~ahold', please?  Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

@Grobu My bad I had used sudo aptitude install miktex instead of seraching. It worked And I have miktex right now. Thanks! (Could you post it as the answer so I check it?)

glad that it worked, but I'd be curious to know what you did to fix the problem. Were you able to identify broken+held packages thanks to aptitude?  As for the question, I suppose you could just close it, since it's not really bout programming stuff and it would probably better belong on other StackExchange websites like SuperUser.

@Grobu Yea I just followed your advice and used aptitude search '~b' and aptitude search '~ahold' then I installed by aptitude install miktex.
